# Oracle 11g: INSERT SELECT with WITH statement

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I've written this simple example `DML` with `WITH` statement:

```
WITH seq AS
 (SELECT to_char(LEVEL - 1) p FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10)
SELECT old_value,
       new_value
  FROM (SELECT to_char(t1.p) old_value,
               to_char(t2.p) new_value
          FROM (SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY p) rn,
                       p
                  FROM seq) t1,
               (SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY dbms_random.random) rn,
                       p
                  FROM seq) t2
         WHERE t1.rn = t2.rn);
```

Is there any way to use `WITH` statement in `INSERT` statement?

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c224f/1/0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as mentioned here : https://forums.oracle.com/thread/696477
and here : [insert statement with with clause invalid identifier oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612884/insert-statement-with-with-clause-invalid-identifier-oracle)

the WITH clause is part of the select statemant , so just try to wrap it all with an INSERT statement as below :

```
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE    
WITH seq AS
     (SELECT to_char(LEVEL - 1) p FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10)
    SELECT old_value,
           new_value
      FROM (SELECT to_char(t1.p) old_value,
                   to_char(t2.p) new_value
              FROM (SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY p) rn,
                           p
                      FROM seq) t1,
                   (SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY dbms_random.random) rn,
                           p
                      FROM seq) t2
             WHERE t1.rn = t2.rn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put `insert` on the top.

```
18:04:23 HR@sandbox> create table t (k number, v number);

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.84
23:00:22 HR@sandbox> insert into t
23:00:34   2  with tt as (
23:00:39   3  select rownum, rownum*10 from dual
23:00:47   4  connect by rownum < 10
23:00:54   5  )
23:00:55   6  select * from tt
23:00:58   7  /

9 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.24
```