# INSERT INTO TABLE USING REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: plsql

I'm trying to insert into a table my chaine:

```
'MARIE,CLAIRE,99999|RIM,CHAVANE,66666|RANA,LEONNE,33333';
```

I should have 3 rows in my table as folows:

```
NAME   LAST_NAME PHONE_NUMBER  
-----------------------------
MARIE  CLAIRE    99999
RIM    CHAVANE   66666                      
RANA   LEONNE    33333
```

But i retreive only the first row duplicated
Can you please help?

Below is the script:

```
DECLARE
  NAME         VARCHAR2(200):=NULL ;
  LAST_NAME    VARCHAR2(200):=NULL ;
  PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(200):=NULL ;
  CHAINE       VARCHAR2(200):=NULL ;
  i            NUMBER       :=0;
  n            NUMBER       :=0;
BEGIN
  CHAINE :='MARIE,CLAIRE,99999|RIM,CHAVANE,66666|RANA,LEONNE,33333';

  FOR  i in 1..10
  LOOP
    NAME         := REGEXP_SUBSTR(CHAINE,'[^,]+', 1, 1);
    LAST_NAME    := REGEXP_SUBSTR(CHAINE,'[^,]+', 1, 2);
    PHONE_NUMBER := REGEXP_SUBSTR(CHAINE,'[^,$|]+', 1, 3);
    INSERT INTO test_oum VALUES (NAME,LAST_NAME,PHONE_NUMBER);
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line('NAME        '  || NAME );
  dbms_output.put_line('LAST_NAME     '  || LAST_NAME );
  dbms_output.put_line('PHONE_NUMBER    '  || PHONE_NUMBER );

END;
```

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: Hi,i can't insert the chaine in my table

Comment: Any rational behind looping it 10 times. If the requirement is just to insert 3 records why are you looping for 10 times. Check the belpw solution provided by "Chrisrs2292". It will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that for all you are looping, you are always doing the sub-string on the same commas (i.e. the first, second and third). The "Chaine" variable is not being modified, so you always retrieve the same values.

I think you need to do something similar to the following:

```
DECLARE
  NAME         VARCHAR2(200):=NULL ;
  LAST_NAME    VARCHAR2(200):=NULL ;
  PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(200):=NULL ;
  CHAINE       VARCHAR2(200):=NULL ;
  i            NUMBER       :=0;
  n            NUMBER       :=0;
BEGIN
  CHAINE :='MARIE,CLAIRE,99999|RIM,CHAVANE,66666|RANA,LEONNE,33333';

  FOR cValue IN (
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(chaine ,'[^|]+',1,LEVEL) val FROM DUAL
    connect BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(chaine ,'[^|]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
  )
  LOOP
    NAME         := REGEXP_SUBSTR(cValue.val,'[^,]+', 1, 1);
    LAST_NAME    := REGEXP_SUBSTR(cValue.val,'[^,]+', 1, 2);
    PHONE_NUMBER := REGEXP_SUBSTR(cValue.val,'[^,]+', 1, 3);

    dbms_output.put_line('NAME         '  || NAME );
    dbms_output.put_line('LAST_NAME    '  || LAST_NAME );
    dbms_output.put_line('PHONE_NUMBER '  || PHONE_NUMBER );

    INSERT INTO test_oum VALUES (NAME,LAST_NAME,PHONE_NUMBER);
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

This splits the string on the pipe characters, and loops through each string. It then pulls out the name, last name and phone number by splitting on the commas each time.

Answer (score 1):

In general the PL/SQL constructs should be avoided when the operation can be done with plain old SQL. Usually the resulting code will be more concise and faster. Here you'll see an example with a single SQL insert-select-statement:

```
declare
  v_chaine constant varchar2(32767) := 
    'MARIE,CLAIRE,99999|RIM,CHAVANE,66666|RANA,LEONNE,33333';
begin
  -- note: missing column names in insert statement is not recommended
  insert into test_oum
  with
  -- split single string on '|'
  r(str) as (
    select     regexp_substr(v_chaine ,'[^|]+', 1, level) from dual
    connect by regexp_substr(v_chaine ,'[^|]+', 1, level) is not null
  )
  select
   regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+', 1, 1) as first_name
  ,regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+', 1, 2) as last_name
  ,regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+', 1, 3) as phone_number
  from r
  ;
end;
/
```

See also e.g. [Oracle 11g: INSERT SELECT with WITH statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17837750/272735)

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to declare "i int :=0"

```
DECLARE
  NAME         VARCHAR2(200):=NULL ;
  LAST_NAME    VARCHAR2(200):=NULL ;
  PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(200):=NULL ;
  CHAINE       VARCHAR2(200):=NULL ;
  n            NUMBER       :=0;
BEGIN
  CHAINE :='MARIE,CLAIRE,99999|RIM,CHAVANE,66666|RANA,LEONNE,33333';

  FOR  i in 1..10
  LOOP
    NAME         := REGEXP_SUBSTR(CHAINE,'[^,]+', 1, 1);
    LAST_NAME    := REGEXP_SUBSTR(CHAINE,'[^,]+', 1, 2);
    PHONE_NUMBER := REGEXP_SUBSTR(CHAINE,'[^,$|]+', 1, 3);
    INSERT INTO test_oum VALUES (NAME,LAST_NAME,PHONE_NUMBER);
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line('NAME        '  || NAME );
  dbms_output.put_line('LAST_NAME     '  || LAST_NAME );
  dbms_output.put_line('PHONE_NUMBER    '  || PHONE_NUMBER );

END;
```